# How to resume app from background like tapping app launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm developing a **sticker keyboard** for Android. In the **keyboard layout**, I have a `button`. When I minimize the app then open the keyboard and I tap the button, I want to open my app on the latest screen.

There are steps:

1. Open app (LauncherActivity)
2. Go to Activity 1 (TheFirstActivity)
3. Go to Activity 2 (TheSecondActivity)
4. Minimize the app
5. Open another app and open my keyboard
6. Tap the button.

When I tap the button, I want my app to be opened at the Activity 2 and the app state is restored like the state when the app is minimized.

This is my code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LauncherActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's not working. When I tap the button, I want my app to be opened at the Activity 2 and the app state is restored like the state when the app is minimized.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

use this code for this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LauncherActivity.class);
 // set the new task, clear flags and From History flag 
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take this scenario :

- I assume you have a background service from where you want to resume your activity in a paused state in the background
- and also, you just want to resume the activity with all his previous state as the system does when your app is on pause or like it's done when the notification is clicked.

For that case, you can use the code below

```
   public void resumeActivityFromBackground(Intent intent, boolean restart) {
    if (intent == null)
        intent = new Intent(BackgroundServiceClass.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("activity_started_from_service", true);
    intent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    /*| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED*/);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
    stopSelf(); //Use this to stop the service if you are launching from a background service.
}
```

- Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK - Will is what helps to bring the existing activity from background without recreating a new instance.
- Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP - Will make sure that the activity your are resuming is actually the one on top

This is what worked for me.